# Trying to get form data as XML via REST API

Tags: orbeon

It should be a simple thing and it probably is, but I'm not achieving to get the XML data of a draft form via the REST API described in the Orbeon docs.

I did the following changes to the properties-local-dev.xml file:

```
<property
  as="xs:string"
  processor-name="oxf:page-flow"
  name="page-public-methods"
  value="GET HEAD POST"/>

<property
  as="xs:string"
  processor-name="oxf:page-flow"
  name="service-public-methods"
  value="GET HEAD"/>

<property
  as="xs:anyURI"
  name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.exist-uri"
  value="/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr"/>

<page    public-methods="GET HEAD POST" view="view.xpl"/>
<service public-methods="GET HEAD"      view="view.xpl"/>
```

Then I tried different URL's to call the data:

```
  http://localhost:9090/orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/gsmn/hello-world/draft/f025a471b2c8452dd65267cc5886063d995757f5/data.xml
  http://localhost:9090/orbeon/crud/gsmn/hello-world/draft/f025a471b2c8452dd65267cc5886063d995757f5/data.xml
  http://localhost:9090/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/gsmn/hello-world/draft/f025a471b2c8452dd65267cc5886063d995757f5/data.xml
```

Form Runner resides on :
http://localhost:9090/orbeon/fr/

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks
Noel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app name is `gsmn` and your form name is `hello-world`, then the last URL you mentioned (copied below for clarity), should work.

http://localhost:9090/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/gsmn/hello-world/draft/92aad35a44876b3bfac3b4d6f835130fbd1fe19e/data.xml

However, most likely, the issue is that you're trying this with eXist, and that, as of this writing, the autosave functionality isn't supported by Orbeon Forms on eXist; it is only supported on relational databases. For more on this, see the [support matrix for different databases](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/db-support.html), and the [RFE to add support for autosave on eXist](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1906).

Comment: Hi Alex

Ok, that means that getting the formdata as XML via this REST call only works if there is a database connected, right?

Threrefore I'll try to get a database running with the orbeon server so that I can get the xml data via that REST call.

Thank you

Comment: Other question: Is there a way to make the eXist datastore persistent? So that eXist saves the data in an XML File on the server? Or is it always held in memory?

Regards

Comment: Hi Noel, *drafts* in the context of *autosave* are only supported with relational databases, and are not supported with eXist. To be clear, with eXist, it's not just that the API won't return the draft, it's that there is no autosave happening, and thus no draft in the database that the API could possibly return. -Alex

Comment: Regarding "making the eXist datastore persistent", eXist does save the data in a persistent way; i.e. the data is saved on disk, not just in memory, and survives Tomcat or even the server being restarted. eXist saves the data using files that it manages, not directly as XML on disk. However, you can access the XML saved in eXist using WebDAV. -Alex